# Sorting lists in python without sorted() funtion

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm trying to make a program which adds the player's input to a list that's sorted alphabetically. When I try the program I've come up with it just arranges the words haphazardly, and I don't know whatäs wrong. What am I missing? I am fully aware there's a function which sorts for you, I'm simply doing this for practice.

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
array = []
while True:
    pl_inp = input('Add something to the list:\n')
    location = 0
    list_has_content = False
    for x in reversed(array):
        indx = 0
        if alphabet.find(pl_inp[indx]) == alphabet.find(x[indx]):
            indx += 1
        elif alphabet.find(pl_inp[indx]) > alphabet.find(x[indx]):
            list_has_content = True
            location = array.index(x)
        elif alphabet.find(pl_inp[indx]) < alphabet.find(x[indx]):
           location = array.index(x) + 1
           break
    if location == 0 and list_has_content == True:
        array.insert(location, pl_inp)
    elif location > 0:
        array.insert(location, pl_inp)
    else:
        array.append(pl_inp)
    print(array)
```

Comment: you're not breaking in the second if. Is that deliberate?

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind what this is trying to do?

Comment: I go through what's already in the list (supposedly in order) from the end of the list and compare the word with the words from the list. If the first letter of the new word comes before the first letter of the word I'm comparing with I move on to the next word in the list. If not then it has it's location in the list and I break the loop. So not breaking the loop in the second if is intentional.